# Youtube API V3 - How to filter out search results that are not accessible in my country?

Tags: youtube-api

I've been using the v2 API til now to send a search query from Windows Speech recognition to Youtube and then send the URL of the top relevance result directly to VLC media player. Now that doesn't always work so well because Speech Recognition is somewhat inaccurate of course. However, what really always annoyed me is that as soon as there is even a TINY misspelling in the query, the v2 API would present completely random results e.g. Poets of the Fall - waar will result in some vietnam war video (as opposed to the normal youtube site, where even when in quotation marks with the spelling error, the results still are relevant.

After some research I've discovered that this is a common problem with the v2 API (drastically different results from normal youtube search), however that with the v3 API this problem has been solved, so I got myself an API access key and changed my WSR macro to use the v3 one. Everything works fairly well except one thing: the v3 API will sometimes present a result that is unavailable in my country. This has never happened with the v2 API. I've checked the documentation very thoroughly but I cannot find a method for search queries to send back only videos I can actually watch. This seems like kind of a big oversight to me...

Here's the API query I'm currently using: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Justin%20Bieber%20is%20the%20best&key=myAPIkey&type=video"

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar problem.  Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try regionCode parameter. As per documentation:

> **regionCode** string The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return
>   search results for the specified country. The parameter value is an
>   ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code

.